# jquery pop up gallery from xml data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have added in my HTML page in head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
       $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "AllResponse.xml", // replace with absolute URL of your gallery's xml file
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find('Hotel').each(function() {

                       var url = $(this).find('HotelFrontImage').attr('Url');



                        $('<li></li>').html('<a href="'+url+'" target="_parent"><img src="'+url+'"/></a>').appendTo('#gallery');
                    });

                }

            });

});
</script>
```

and given body tag

but it's not showing pop up in jquery

can you please tell me what is exactly problem in my code

Comment: can you post a sample of the XML?

Comment: What does your XML look like? Do you get errors in the console?

Comment: 1) Check that your XML arrives
2) Check if it's valid and has the nodes needed

Comment: i need to see u r jquery image pop up gallery plugin. if u r xml data is correct then u can not add dynamically image to jquery image pop up gallery i thick so. put that jquery image pop up gallery plugin link here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('body').append($('<ul />', { 'id': 'gallery' }));

            var xml = $.parseXML('<Hotels><Hotel id="1"><Name>Taj 1</Name><HotelFrontImage Url="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-y301Ju4n32g/TRCtzBfoiZI/AAAAAAAAABc/3tGEuAD3R8I/w487-h365-k/51.jpg"></HotelFrontImage>'
                              + '</Hotel><Hotel id="2"><Name>Taj 2</Name><HotelFrontImage Url="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ZkMSKCbY0Y8/TRCpCX5p35I/AAAAAAAAABQ/ZL2nsL-ir7U/s277/3.jpg"></HotelFrontImage>'
                              + '</Hotel><Hotel id="3"><Name>Taj 3</Name><HotelFrontImage Url="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-y301Ju4n32g/TRCtzBfoiZI/AAAAAAAAABc/3tGEuAD3R8I/s800/51.jpg"></HotelFrontImage></Hotel></Hotels>');

            $(xml).find('Hotel').each(function () {
                var Url = $(this).find('HotelFrontImage').attr('Url');
                $('<li></li>').html('<a href="' + Url + '" target="_parent"><img src="' + Url + '"/></a>').appendTo('#gallery');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: here xml tags are small letters like hotelFrontImage, url <hotel id="1">
    <name>Taj 1</name>
    <hotelFrontImage url="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-y301Ju4n32g/TRCtzBfoiZI/AAAAAAAAABc/3tGEuAD3R8I/w487-h365-k/51.jpg"></hotelFrontImage>
  </hotel> . but in jquery you are using caps letter  then it will give undefined value. $(this).find('HotelFrontImage').attr('Url');

Comment: i need to see u r jquery image pop up gallery plugin. if u r xml data is correct then u can not add dynamically image to jquery image pop up gallery i thick so. put that jquery image pop up gallery plugin link here.